# Bitrix. Открытие веб форм на Андроид-е

Tags: android, битрикс, формы

Есть страница с товарами. Разместил кнопку которая открывает всплывающее окно с веб формой. Все товары вставляются на страницу в цикле соответственно кнопка тоже. Веб форма одна. На ПК открывает нормально с любой кнопки. На андроиде же не открывает. Так же разместил эту кнопку в самом товаре, тобишь там она одна и там она открывается. Подскажите как решить проблему на странице с товарами?

**EDIT#1**: даже если эта кнопка одна, форму не открывает.

**EDIT#2**: Когда юзер не авторизован форму не открывает везде и на Пк и на андроиде. В консоли на пк же ошибка: **VM13370:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined**

Comment: На Android тоже есть несколько браузеров. В каком именно не открывает?

Comment: @metalurgus В Хроме.

Comment: Так для хрома же есть удаленная отладка

Comment: @metalurgus уже проблема в другом. Когда юзер не авторизован форму не открывает везде и на Пк и на андроиде. В консоли на пк же ошибка: **VM13370:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined**

Comment: Задайте вопрос по новой проблеме

Comment: @metalurgus http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550151/bitrix-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-fancybox-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C