# Открытие веб форм при помощи fancybox (не авторизованный пользователь)

Tags: битрикс, form, auth

Использую стандартные веб формы Bitrix. Создал кнопку на сайте,которая при нажатии, при помощи Ajax, подгружает форму и открывает в модальном окне. открытие в окне сделано на fancybox. Проблема в том что когда я авторизован форму открывает на всех страницах сайта. Когда я не авторизован форма открывается на главной странице и на странице товара. на второй и третьей глубине форма не открывается, при это в консоль(Хрома) пишет такую ошибку:

> VM26703:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

вод в VM26703:

```
if (top.BX.ajax.history.bHashCollision) top.BX.ajax.history.checkRedirectFinish('bxajaxid', 'e64f5e91a45eff43e702620a388eff2e');
```

Код вызова формы:

```
$('a.button').fancybox({
    'overlayShow': false,
    'padding': 0,
    'margin' : 0,
    'scrolling' : 'no',
    'titleShow': false,
    'type': 'ajax',
    'href': SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH + '/ajax/buy1click_form.php',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Помогло это:

```
<? 
if (!$USER->IsAuthorized()) { 
CJSCore::Init(array('ajax', 'json', 'ls', 'session', 'jquery', 'popup','pull')); 
} 
?>
```

Добавить в `header.php` после `<?$APPLICATION->ShowHead()?>`